# How can I create veins on skin

Tags: shape-keys

I have this character's arm.

[image]
[image]

I want to have some veins in this pattern with a shape-key, meaning that the basis would be without the veins and when the shape-key is on, the veins would appear. I also don't want to have too many vertices, my computer isn't the best, and I have many other meshes in scene.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I'd try using the knife tool (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html) and bevel to create the geometry where you want your veins to be and create the shapekey by just dragging the geometry out

Comment: @aky-her, I really like your idea on the knife tool but I dont understand what you mean by the bevel tool. And by the way, thank you so much.

Comment: bevel tool (ctrl-B; https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) bevels an edge - adds more geometry, which is smoothed. What it would do here, is take your one line created by the knife tool and make it into two/three/how many you want.

Comment: @aky-her, I just wanna say that your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

I'd do it in the material via a normal map / bump map.